# Using Single Page Application (Spa) Prerendering not returning the correct URL path through IIS AspNetCoreModule

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, single-page-application, iis-10

I have managed to set up a Single Page Application Angular project using .NET Core Prerendering and can confirm that the Angular application works both server and client side.

I'm running the application in IIS 10 using the AspNetCoreModule handler built in Production mode. Again, I can confirm this is working.

I'm having an issue with what is returned in the context of the SpaPrendering every time the page is reloaded, in particular the relative path. It always returns /index.html, rather then the relative path in the browser.

I have tried this in IIS Express in Visual Studio and the relative path returns the correct result. So it seems to be isolated to IIS and using the AspNetCoreModule handler.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5443); //HTTP port               
        })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp";
        });

        services.AddDbContext<DevResourceDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevResourceDbContext")));

        services.AddScoped<ImageService>();
        services.AddScoped<EnquiryService>();
        services.AddScoped<CategoryService>();

        services.AddSingleton<RouteBackgroundService>();

        // Mapping
        services.AddAutoMapper();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        try
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                //app.UseHsts();                      
            }


            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();                
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("index.html", "/"));

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";


                spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
                {
                // If not working, make sure that npm install and npm install @angular-devkit/build-webpack have been ran.
                options.BootModulePath = $"ClientApp/dist-server/ClientApp/main.js";
                    options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
                        ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr")
                        : null;
                    options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };

                    options.SupplyData = (context, data) =>
                    {

                        var routeBackgroundService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RouteBackgroundService>();
                        data["routes"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Paths = routeBackgroundService.GetRouteData() }, Formatting.Indented);

                        // context.Request.Path always returns index.html, even if 
                        GetSupplyData(context, new Uri(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", context.Request.Scheme, context.Request.Host, context.Request.Path, context.Request.QueryString)), data);
                    };
                });



                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void GetSupplyData(HttpContext context, Uri uri, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        var routeBackgroundService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RouteBackgroundService>();

        var path = uri.AbsolutePath;

        // Remove forward slash from path.
        if (path.Length > 0 && path.Substring(0, 1) == "/")
        {
            path = path.Substring(1, path.Length - 1);
        }

        // Does the path match a category?
        var selectedCategory = routeBackgroundService.GetCategory(path);

        if (selectedCategory != null)
        {
            data["selectedCategory"] = Map(context, selectedCategory);

            // Filter the image categories
            var imageCategories = routeBackgroundService.GetImageCategoryByCategory(selectedCategory.Id);

            // Now get the images.
            var images = routeBackgroundService.GetImageByCategory(imageCategories).Select(s => Map(context, s)).ToList();

            if (images != null)
            {
                data["images"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new PageList<Image>(images, uri, uri.ToPageNumber() ?? 1, 12, 5), Formatting.Indented);
            }
        }

        // Ensure all querystring are added to the data.
        var queryData = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

        foreach (var q in queryData.AllKeys)
        {
            data["querystring_" + q] = queryData[q];
        }
    }

    protected Image Map(HttpContext context, ImageEntity entity)
    {
        var mapper = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();

        return mapper.Map<ImageEntity, Image>(entity);
    }

    protected Category Map(HttpContext context, CategoryEntity entity)
    {
        var mapper = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();

        return mapper.Map<CategoryEntity, Category>(entity);
    }
}
```

Inside the StartUp class, there is a Configure void. Inside the Configure void, there is a app.UseSpa where you can configure options. Inside app.UseSpa, I am using spa.UsePreRendering.

When a page is loaded from the server, it runs through the options.SupplyData inside spa.UsePrerendering. One of the parameters inside options.SupplyData is context which is of type HttpContext.

However, when a page is loaded from the server, context.Request.Path always returns index.html, regardless of the path inputted in the browser. So if I was to put http://domain/test, I would expect context.Request.Path to show /test, but it always returns /index.html. I'm guessing it's doing this because the default HTML page for the Angular application is /index.html.

This only happens in IIS 10 using AspNetCoreModule and not using IIS Express inside Visual Studio.

Comment: VS and IIS Express put your web app under a site directly. So on IIS you should create a site and map to your web app folder, and don't create an application.

Answer (score 1):

To make client-side routing work, ASP.NET should return index.html for all requests, no matter what actual path is. Otherwise, we would get a 404 error. But for pre-rendered application, we actually do have all those needed index.html files.

Therefore instead of using

```
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp";
    });
```

you may try setting static files routing manually in public void

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env): {
...
}
```

path to client app:

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp", "dist", "ClientApp"));
```

We also need to tell our provider that `index.html` should be served when we have slash-ending `/` without the exact file name specified.

```
    var defOptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
    defOptions.FileProvider = fileProvider;
    app.UseDefaultFiles(defOptions);
```

And now we should tell that SPA files should be server using our provider for all requests. (If there are existing controllers or Web API requests those would work just OK)

```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = fileProvider,
        RequestPath = new PathString("")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HttpContext.Request.Path property is indeed correct in Development mode, but in production HttpContext.Request.Path = "/index.html".

However, you actually can find the url in the HttpContext.Features.RawTarget private property. It's not accessible publicly, but with reflection you can get its value:

```
var fc = context.Features.GetType();
var rt = fc.GetProperty("RawTarget");
var path = (string)rt.GetValue(context.Features);
```

I've written a package that facilitates supplying data during server-side rendering:

- GitHub: https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing
- Reference to the line where I process the request path correctly: https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/Services/SpaRouteService.cs#L303
- NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/